# Report Builder (Display Time at different time zone) in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I am beginner in ssrs report builder. I want to display the Malaysia(UTC+08:00) time on report trough textbox. The server is on Arizona Chandler. Below are the code which only display Arizona Chandler time

```
=Format(Now(), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt")
```

I want to display as below

```
Malaysia time : 30-Jul-2017 20:27
Arizona Time : 30-Jul-2017  05:27
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DATEADD` to add 15 hours to the current time.

```
=Format(DATEADD(DateInterval.Hour, 15,Now()), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt")
```